# Linear Programming:What combination of two loams to minimize cost

Tags: linear-programming

I am fairly new to linear programming so simplification would be helpful.
Came across a certain question and unfortunately no answer for it at the back of the book. The question is adopted from a book called *An Introduction To Linear Programming And Game Theory by Paul R. Thie*.
The question goes:

> Premium loam is 60% soil, 40% domestic manure, and costs 5dollars per 50lb. Generic loam is 20% soil, 10% domestic manure (and 70% sand,stone,etc) and costs $1 per 50lb. We need loam for our backyard that is at least 36% soil and at least 20% domestic manure. What combination of the two loams should we use to minimize costs?

So far I have done the following:

- Let x be the amount of premium loam bought in lb (pounds) =decision variable

  Let y be the amount of generic loam bought in lb (pounds) =decision variable

Then some functions which if I'm not mistaken are called objective functions:
0.6x + 0.2y \ge 36 
 0.4x + 0.1y \ge 20 
What else am I missing and how do I go about solving the problem?

Comment: Is there another condition like, 50 lb loam is needed for our backyard?

Comment: Right. This question doesn't really make sense without a restriction on how much loam is needed.

Comment: I will bet it doesn't matter. The answer probably scales with the absolute amount. You probably do have to pick something, however, so let's say 50 total pounds.

Comment: no total amount of loam is mentioned in the question @MarkG

Answer (score 2):

One way to get around the the lack of a restraint on the total amount produced is:

Let $x$ be the number of pounds of premium loam used in the production of 100lbs of your final mixture. Let $y$ be the number of pounds of generic loam used in the production of 100lbs of your final mixture.

The problem is to $$\min \; \frac{5}{50}x + \frac{1}{50}y$$ subject to
\begin{align}
0.6x + 0.2y &\ge 36 \\
0.4x + 0.1y &\ge 20 \\
x+y&=100\\
x &\ge 0 \\
y &\ge 0 \\
\end{align}

Comment: Exactly. Well done.